# How to space-phase-transform an ode - and why?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the given ODE:

$$y'' + 4y = 0$$

and I have to write it in the form $\bf{x}'=F(x)$ and phase-transform it to new variables $\bf{x}$=$(x_1,x_2...)$, is there anything else to do but writing it simply as:

$$x_2'' + 4x_2 = 0$$ ?

Since this is only one ODE, and not a system, it appears quite "simple" and "meaningless". Any ideas what the purpose of this is?

Thanks

Comment: The idea is to get a first order ODE instead of a second order ODE - see Gino's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=\begin{bmatrix}
y\\y'
\end{bmatrix}:=\begin{bmatrix}
x(1)\\x(2)
\end{bmatrix}$. Then:

$x'=\begin{bmatrix}
y'\\y''
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
x(2)\\-4\,x(1)
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
-4&0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x(1)\\x(2)
\end{bmatrix}=Ax$

The reason why you should express any ODE into a state space form is to reduce the order of differentiation from $n$ to $1$. For ODE of order $1$, there are well-established theorems, algorithms and methodologies that can be applied more successfully and efficiently.

Comment: From your differential equation, you have y''=-4y=-4x(1)

Comment: Got it, thanks!